# calling a method on the parent page from a user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, methods

I am using a user control that I created (just a .cs file not an .ascx file), that does some magic and depending on a value generated by the control, I need it to do something on the parent page that is 'hosting' the control.  It needs to call a method under certain circumstances (method is on the parent control).

the control is placed on the parent page like so:

```
<customtag:MyControl ID="something" runat="server" />
```

I'm dynamically creating buttons etc on the control itself but when a button is clicked, let's say for example that there's a text box on the control and if the value of the textbox is "bob" it needs to call a method on the page that's housing the control...how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* do what casperOne suggested, but I wouldn't advise it. This is tightly coupling your user control to your parent page, which kind of defeats the purpose of a user control.

Personally, I'd add an event to the user control (say, `ButtonClicked`) that the parent page can handle. In the event handler in your parent, deal with the event however you see fit. This way you can plug the user control into a different page at a later date and not have to worry about logic in the user control that *requires* a specific kind of parent page.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the Page hosting the control through the [Parent property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.parent.aspx).  However, that's going to be returned to you as a Control.  You have to cast it to the type of your page in order to access any methods on the page which you have defined.

Answer (score 0):

I think that casperOne is on the right track, but you need to go a step further.  I'm giong to make the assumption that this user control will be used on more then on page.  (I normally write VB.Net, sorry if my C# is malformed)

Make a base page class (you can store it in your App_Code directory or in a project):

```
public class PageToInheritFrom : System.Web.UI.Page {
    public void SpecialFunction() {
    }    
}
```

Now make sure that all of your pages inherit from this page in your code behind file:

```
public partial class _Default : PageToInheritFrom {

}
```

Now in your user control you know what the page type is and can call

```
((PageToInheritFrom)this.Page).SpecialFunction();
```